# Different between parseLine and parseLineMulti in opencsv's CSVParser

Tags: java, opencsv

By referring to https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVParser.java

Anyone has idea what is the different among `parseLine` and `parseLineMulti` in opencsv's `CSVParser`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code it seems to determine whether to check the next line for a remainder of quoted text when the quotation doesn't end in the current line.

If you use `parseLine` it will throw an exception rather than check the subsequent lines.

Following is the relevant code snippet.

```
if (inQuotes) {
            if (multi) {

                // continuing a quoted section, re-append newline

                sb.append("\n");

                pending = sb.toString();

                sb = null; // this partial content is not to be added to field list yet
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Un-terminated quoted field at end of CSV line");

            }
        }
```